# Web stress testing of AngularJS SPA ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, performance-testing

Is it possible to test AngularJS SPA application developed using ASP.NET MVC with Visual Studio or any other alternative tool for the same purpose?

Comment: For Angular JS or React JS like applications, traditional protocol (HTTP/HTML) is not a right choice. Stay away from Web HTTP/HTML protocol. Even if you record the application, it will captures only the service calls. To measure the performance use UI layer protocol such as TruClient for Web or JMeter Web Driver sampler. Run your script with only one user AND in the background you need to run the appropriate web service calls for the actual load. Blend of both the scripts yields the better performance metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above issue by using a headless browser (*PhantomJS*). I wrote a script to simulate user logging into the angular application and loading the inbox. But this way I was able to test only one user.

We cannot span multiple instances of *PhantomJS*, so I created 100 copies of the *PhantomJS* and then wrote a script to launch all these 100 copies to span 1 process of *PhantomJS* per file, the solution worked like a charm for load testing a SPA website.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo, for making changes.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a Visual Studio version which includes load testing framework the answer is yes, see [Get started with performance testing](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-performance-testing) for details.

If you don't have a matching Visual Studio edition you can consider any other load testing tool, for example see http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview

Any tool which supports HTTP/HTTPS protocols will play for you.

The most outstanding free and open source load testing tools are listed and compared in the [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article.

Comment: If have Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. But the problem is VS Test does not see the HTML generated for the pages as valid HTML as AngularJS have it's own conventions for HTML. Plus the clientside rendering of GUI is not performed and the VS recorder could not record all the AJAX and Async calls to the server(I can see in the fiddler many behind the scene call are being recorded by the fiddler). So I don't find Visual Studio to be able to run a test perfectly. If you have done so please let me know how can I do it, or any related documentation link.

Comment: If you are using Fiddler and still want to use MSVS you can just [export captured requests](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Save-And-Load-Traffic/Tasks/VSWebTest) as `File Export->All Sessions->Select Export Format -> Visual Studio WebTests` and import them into your VS project. For other tools see i.e. [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter)